# Issue getting fadeIn element to raise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have four boxes that are displayed in a single row (in a larger viewport). The boxes then `fadeIn` will going up the page. My issue is I cannot figure out how to get these boxes to go up the page without affecting the parent div and the sections of code below it (`#contact-social`). I want the other to divs to stay in their finished place that they are supposed to be in (after the boxes have went up the page).

How can I only change the positioning of the boxes as they go up the page without affecting anything else?

The position I have in my

```js
function contactBox() {
  $('.contact-connect-box').delay(600).animate({
   'opacity' : 1,
 'margin' : "0px 20px"
  }, 800);
};
contactBox();
```

```css
 #contact-connect {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 10%;
    padding: 80px 0;
   }
    .contact-connect-box {
    width: 22%;
    margin: 60px 20px 0 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    opacity: 0;
   }
#contact-social {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contact-connect">
  <div class="contact-connect-box">
   <h2 class="contact-connect-title">fda</h2>
   <div class="contact-connect-description">fdsaf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-connect-box">
   <h2 class="contact-connect-title">fdsa</h2>
   <div class="contact-connect-description">
    Reach out to us
    <br>
    <div id="scroll" class="contact-connect-link">fdsaf</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-connect-box">
   <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Visit</h2>
   <div class="contact-connect-description">
    fdsaf
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-connect-box">
   <h2 class="contact-connect-title">fdf</h2>
   <div class="contact-connect-description">
    <div class="contact-connect-link"><a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">fds</a></div>
    <div class="contact-connect-link"><a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">fdsfe</a></div>
    <div class="contact-connect-link"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="contact-social">
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent other elements move - making a margin top smaller, you should also increase the bottom margin respectively...

Or, instead of animating the `margin`, add a CSS class that will `transition` your styles :

```js
function contactBox() {
  $('.contact-connect-box').addClass("fadeShow");
};
setTimeout(contactBox, 600);
```

```css
#contact-connect {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 10%;
  padding: 80px 0;
}
.contact-connect-box {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 60px 20px 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 0;
  transition:2s; -webkit-transition:2s; /* ADD THIS */
}

.contact-connect-box.fadeShow{ /* AND ALL OF THIS */
  opacity:1;
  transform:translateY(-30px); -webkit-transform:translateY(-30px);
}


#contact-social {
  height: 200px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contact-connect">
  <div class="contact-connect-box">
    <h2 class="contact-connect-title">fda</h2>
    <div class="contact-connect-description">fdsaf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-connect-box">
    <h2 class="contact-connect-title">fdsa</h2>
    <div class="contact-connect-description">
      Reach out to us
      <br>
      <div id="scroll" class="contact-connect-link">fdsaf</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-connect-box">
    <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Visit</h2>
    <div class="contact-connect-description">
      fdsaf

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-connect-box">
    <h2 class="contact-connect-title">fdf</h2>
    <div class="contact-connect-description">
      <div class="contact-connect-link"><a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">fds</a></div>
      <div class="contact-connect-link"><a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">fdsfe</a></div>
      <div class="contact-connect-link"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="contact-social">

</div>
```

Comment: I don't quite fully understand what you mean. Am I putting my normal margin back within my css and then adding in the translate into my animate function?

Comment: Normal margin being what is in the JS

Comment: @Becky CSS3 `translate` will not move other elements. Otherwise, as you make the margin top smaller you should increase the bottom margin as-well for the same (missing) top value

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect. I wanted to use a CSS3 solution initially, just wasn't sure how to do it. This is some-what off topic, but when using `translateY` and `translateX`, the Y is for vertical movement and the X is for horizontal, correct?

Comment: @Becky (You're welcome) Exactly, you can use `translate(valX, valY)` or `translate3d(valX, valY, valZ)` or `translateX(valX)` or `translateY(valY)`

Comment: Great! I'll look more into it. Appreciate the help again!

Comment: @Becky I suppose now you can remove that initial 60px top margin and set it to the the desired state (20px?) than you can move it as normal (initially hidden) down using `translateY(20px)` and do `translateY(0px)` inside the `.fadeShow` class. Hope makes sense.

Comment: @Becky glad I could help! Happy coding